# How to disable notepad++ autocomplete

Tags: notepad++

I want to turn off autocompletion on words in notepad++

[image]

Or at least have something more discreet.

Comment: Installed on Windows 8.1 64 bit. `Enable auto-completion` is unchecked, but anyway notepad++ suggests functions. So i checked `Enable auto-completion`, set From 9 th character and checked radio button Function completion

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Got to 'Settings' >> 'Preferences' >> 'Auto-Completion' and untick 'Enable auto-completion on each input'

Comment: what is "function parameters hint"?

Answer (score 2):

@user1603548 - if you are editing a computer language file npp can show you the function parameters for well known functions.  For example, edit a file called test.c which npp will recognize as the "C" language.  Type "m" and the first auto-suggestion is malloc. Click tab to select malloc and type ( so that you have "malloc("  If you have function parameters hint enabled you Npp will show a hoverbox with "void malloc (size_t size);"  The "size_t size" part is the function parameter. Npp shows the entire function definition including its parameters in the hint.

If the function that's being hinted has more than one parameter then the hint thing highlights the parameter that you are on as you enter them in the file. This can be quite useful for functions that take many parameters as you then won't loose track of where you are in the list.

Npp also supports disabling "enable auto-completion on each input" and enabling "function parameters hint on input". When used this way npp will not suggest malloc() and other functions related to the C language but will show the function parameter hints.

Function parameters hints are is just a hint and not act like auto-complete. You can't hit tab or any other key to drop the contents of the displayed hint into the file you are editing.

Unfortunately, the hints are not available for HTML files even though npp is a popular editor for HTML.